# command --help vs man command

Tags: man, documentation

What is the difference between invoking the help using a --help key compared to invoking a "man command"?

When should I choose one over another.

Comment: Any answer in [Why do some commands have man pages and other commands use --help?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1832/why-do-some-commands-have-man-pages-and-other-commands-use-help)?

Comment: By the way, there are also info pages, reachable as `info command`. See [What is GNU Info for?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77514/what-is-gnu-info-for) for more.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate, voting to close.

Comment: That's @manatwork doing what a man at work does. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Help is a built-in "usage" of the command, and not all commands implement it, or at least not the same way, however, `man` is a command by itself which is a pager program that reads manual. For more info issue the `man man` for the manual pages for the `man` command.

You should use man every time you need additional information about a command, as well with the `info` command, that reads info documents.