# Does info also look up manpage?

Tags: man, info

Besides `man`, `info` can also provide information of a command.

1. For the commands I have tried, I find that `info` provides the same
   information as `man`. So I wonder if `info` always look up manpages?
   What else does it also loop up? I.e. what is its source?
2. Do the two provide info for the same set of commands?

Answer (score 4):

### So I wonder if info always look up manpages?

(Assuming that your question is about `standalone-info`)
Your suspicion is indeed correct. If the standalone program `info` can not find the corresponding info page, it will look up the man page. It can be demonstrated as follows

First, let us create a man page that does not exist either as man or info. Let us make a fictions command `mexico` that has no man or info.

To confirm:

`` $ man mexico
No manual entry for mexico
$ info mexico
(opens in Info, but displaces Top)
No menu item `mexico' in node `(dir)Top'. ``

Now, create a simple manpage, and make sure it is in the path.

`$ mkdir -p $HOME/.myman/man0
$ cat > $HOME/.myman/man0/mexico.0
.TH MEXICO 0 "2018" "Mexico Version 0.0"
.SH SEE ALSO
adisababa(0), timbuktu(0)`

And see that it is accessible from `man`. The invocation of man is `man [section] <name>`.

`export MANPATH=$HOME/.myman:$MANPATH
export MANSECT=$MANSECT:0
man 0 mexico`

Check the same from `info`. The invocation is `info <node> [topic]`. This should open up the same page in info.

`info mexico 0`

Unfortunately, info does this only if the info node is not found. If the node is found, but topic is not, info will simply open that info node, and say the topic was not found. The hint that it is using man pages will be on the first line of info. It should say *File: *manpages**.

Unfortunately, the `info` [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/info-stnd.html) says nothing about this.

### What else does it also look up? I.e. what is its source?

As far as I can tell from the [source](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/texinfo/trunk/info/man.c) (since it mentions nothing about it in the official docs), it can read man pages, but the [sources](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/texinfo/trunk/info/) suggests nothing else (other than plain info).

The `info` pages are typically installed in a few system directories. These can be located by greping for '/info' in the strings

`` strings `which info` | grep /info ``

Further info directories can be set by updating [`INFOPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Other-Info-Directories.html#Other-Info-Directories). The info files are generated from a their [texinfo](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/index.html#Top) source.

### Do the two provide info for the same set of commands?

No, `info` and `man` are two separate utilities with different documentation pages. Many developers prefer to provide both info and man pages, but they exist separately, and some developers may decide to provide only one or the other. As I mentioned previously, info can read man pages **if corresponding info files are not found** (and you can determine when it is reading a man page). (Man pages are an older system, and does not fall back to info pages at all).

Comment: Very good answer. Note that you can use `M-x man` if you want to display a man page in `info` regardless of whether an `info` entry exists for the topic or not.

Comment: Note that it's not uncommon for man and info pages to be generated from the same source. For instance, zsh info and man pages are both generated from the same yodl source.

Answer (score 1):

No, `info` is a [separate utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info/info.html), with separate pages. However, nothing stops program authors/documentors from providing the same information for both.

Comment: `info` displays man pages if no entry is found in the info directory. You can use `M-x man` within info to get to a specific man page (regardless of whether there's an info entry for the topic or not). See @rahul's answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

In the following notes, it is important to not confuse Texinfo (`texinfo`), the stand-alone info reader (`info`) and the info reader embedded in GNU Emacs (`M-x info`).

> There are two primary Info readers: `info`, a stand-alone program
>   designed just to read Info files (see What is Info?)
>   and the `info` package in GNU Emacs, a general-purpose editor.

Texinfo manual: chapter Overview, section Adding Output Formats:

> From time to time, proposals are made to generate traditional Unix man pages from Texinfo source. However, because man pages have a strict conventional format, **creating a good man page requires a completely different source from that needed for the typical Texinfo applications of writing a good user tutorial and/or a good reference manual**. This makes generating man pages incompatible with the Texinfo design goal of not having to document the same information in different ways for different output formats. You might as well write the man page directly.

An info manual has a completely different structure than a `man` page, see [What is GNU Info for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77514/what-is-gnu-info-for).

According to @Kyle Jones, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77533

> The original Texinfo processor and Info document *browser* were both written in Lisp and ran inside Emacs. **The standalone Texinfo utilities came several years later.**

Info standalone: chapter Stand-alone Info

> Emacs Info and stand-alone Info have **nearly identical user interfaces**, although customization and other details are different (this manual explains the stand-alone Info reader).

Moreover, GNU Emacs may read a `man` page (man package, installed by default) and the Info system (`makeinfo`, `info`, ...) is based on the principle of creating a **documentation system**¹. Look at the built-in documentation system of GNU Emacs: `M-x describe-function`, type `man` and `Enter`.

> man is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in `man.el`.
>
> (man MAN-ARGS)
>
> Get a Un#x manual and put it in a buffer. This command is the top-level command in the man package. **It runs a Un#x command to retrieve and clean a manpage** in the background and places the result in a `Man-mode` browsing buffer. [...]
>
> For a manpage from a particular section, use either of the following. "cat(1)" is how cross-references appear and is passed to man as "1 cat".
>
> ```
>     cat(1)
>     1 cat
> ```
>
> To see manpages from all sections related to a subject, use an "all pages" option (which might be "-a" if it's not the default), then step through with `Man-next-manpage` (M-n) etc. Add to `Man-switches` to make this option permanent.
>   [...]

We can know which source the Info reader will use, using the options `-aw`. For more information, look at the manual "info-stnd", section "Invoking Info".

```
prompt% info -aw dmesg
*manpages*
prompt% info -aw printf
/usr/share/info/libc.info.bz2
*manpages*
```

---

¹ <sub>For more information, read the manual Texinfo.</sub>