# Does the info command display man pages?

Tags: man, info

I was looking for a way to follow "hyperlinks" in man pages, when I stumbled across the `info` command, which seemed to display information on commands the same as `man` but also allows you to tab to hyperlinks (and sadly no vim keybindings, but the arrow keys work)

But it made me wonder if this command was just displaying man pages with different formatting and functionality of display...or if it was displaying something else entirely like a separate set of documentation.

Comment: Did you try `info man` and `man info` ?

Comment: Yes, and `info info` and `man man` only the later produces a result.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if the documentation in the `man info` is the same "documentation" that `man` has.

Comment: I think the answer is "sometimes" - see for example [Does info also look up manpage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144105/does-info-also-look-up-manpage)

Comment: `info` has a `--vi-keys` option for (a subset of) vim keybindings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`man` and `info` use different primary sources of information: `man` displays manpages, typically stored in `/usr/share/man`, while `info` displays Info documents, typically stored in `/usr/share/info`. Additionally, Info documents are normally available in a tree structure, rooted in `/usr/share/info/dir`, the “Directory node” displayed when you start `info`.

Whether a given manpage contains the same information as its corresponding Info document depends on who authored both. In some cases, they’re produced from a common source, or one is produced from the other; but in many cases they’re different.

GNU `info` will display a manpage if it doesn’t find an Info document. [Pinfo](http://pinfo.sourceforge.net/) can also display both Info documents and manpages, and it provides hyperlinks in manpages; its key bindings can also be configured to match your tastes.

Answer (score 7):

The [`info` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info_(Unix)) displays documentation available in Info format. This is a document format that supports basic text formatting (less than modern `man`), documents consisting of multiple logical pages, and hyperlinks.

Info files are usually generated from [texinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo) sources, which can be transformed both into Info documentation that's readable in a text terminal, nicer printable text in a format such as PDF, or HTML. The Info format is older than HTML.

The Info format started out as Emacs's documentation format. There's a more fancy Info browser built into Emacs, and `info` is available for non-Emacs users. The standalone `info` browser is fairly minimalistic and doesn't have configurable key bindings, and since it comes from GNU it naturally has Emacs-like key bindings. If you want an Info browser with vi-like key bindings, use Emacs and one of its vi emulation packages.

The [full documentation of `info`](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/html_node/index.html) is part of the [texinfo package](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/). Your distribution may package the documentation separately from the executable due to [license concerns over GNU documentation](https://www.debian.org/vote/2006/vote_001); for example, Debian ships it in [`texinfo-doc-nonfree`](https://packages.debian.org/texinfo-doc-nonfree).

If you run `info foo` and there's no `foo` available in the Info documentation, the `info` utility tries calling `man foo`, and if that succeeds, `info` displays the man page rendered by `man` in `info`'s interface.

Answer (score 3):

`man` and `info` are different approaches to providing tools' / commands' manuals. For example, from `man tar`:

> **NOTE**
>
> This manpage is a short description of GNU tar.  For a detailed discussion, including examples and usage recommendations, refer to the
>   GNU Tar Manual available in texinfo format.  If the info reader and the tar documentation are properly installed on your system, the command
>
> **info tar**
>
> should give you access to the complete manual.

It may happen, though, that, for certain commands, an `info` data set doesn't exist, or falls back to the (reduced) contents of the `man` page.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `man` <kbd>Return</kbd> `info` <kbd>Return</kbd> gives you the man page for the `info` program within the `info` program.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be able to view info and man pages with the ability to follow links, colorful display and vim bindings, try [info.vim](https://gitlab.com/HiPhish/info.vim) (tips in [Is there a more interactive man and info pages viewer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656544/is-there-a-more-interactive-man-and-info-pages-viewer/704313#704313)).

Leaving this here as it took myself many months to look in the most obvious place for vim bindings...